# mysql : possible to put IF statment in LEFT JOIN?

Tags: php, mysql

Ok so i want to get an artists info from the db, but i want to know if they have any forthcoming events. To do this i need to traverse 2 tables, where events_artists is a 2 col link table...

(this doesnt work but is what id like to do)

```
SELECT art.*, events.event_id FROM art 
LEFT JOIN events_artists
ON art.art_id = events_artists.art_id
LEFT JOIN events
ON events_artists.event_id = events.event_id IF ( {criteria} )
```

what should i be doing here to get this to work?!!

Comment: I don't see why you'd be LEFT JOINing to the `EVENTS` table.  The impression I have is these should all be JOINs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `AND` keyword to specify additional criteria on the join.

```
SELECT art.*, events.event_id FROM art 
LEFT JOIN events_artists
ON art.art_id = events_artists.art_id
LEFT JOIN events
ON events_artists.event_id = events.event_id AND ( {criteria} )
```

If necessary, you could also use a subquery such as `AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tbl)` if you need to query additional data.